# Selenium click a button

Tags: selenium

I am trying to click a  button:

```
<button type="button" class="yt-ui-menu-item yt-uix-menu-close-on-select vm-playlist-monetize-videos">
    <span class="yt-ui-menu-item-label">Monetize</span>
</button>
```

I have tried the following:

```
//*[@id=\"aria-menu-id-7\"]/ul/li[1]/button/span
```

Which won't work because the id is sometimes different than 7

I have also trued

```
//span[.='Monetize']
```

Which also doesn't work. How can I go about getting the xpath to click the above button?

Comment: Why don't you access elements by property and tag name?

Answer (score 0):

You can try **starts-with** function if the **id** property is not unique. Try following **xpath**:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'aria-menu-id')]/descendant::button/span[text()='Monetize']
```

Let me know, if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, using `explicit wait` method along with `xpath`.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);  //wait for 10 seconds to find the web-elment.
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button/span[text()='Monetize']"))));
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button/span[text()='Monetize']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Click the button not the span element

```
//*[text()='Monetize'][@class='yt-ui-menu-item-label']/..
(or use the below format)
//*[contains(text(),'Monetize')][@class='yt-ui-menu-item-label']/..
```